# Debayer video with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, pixelformat

Looking to debayer video with ffmpeg. I can't find a way to do it without piping raw video between two instances of ffmpeg, because I can't change the pixel format of my input video "in place" from gray to bayer_gbrg8. So, this command works:

```
ffmpeg -i fr_losslessmovie_png_codec.avi -f image2pipe -pix_fmt gray \
-vcodec rawvideo - | ffmpeg -r 25 -f rawvideo -s 2048x700 \
-pix_fmt bayer_gbrg8 -i pipe:0 -y -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 25000k \
fr_debayer_compressed.mp4
```

I would have given the source movie this pixel format, but didn't realize ffmpeg suported bayered pixel formatting.

Didn't see this exact question online, and have not found a way to change the pixel format with video filters etc. without ffmpeg thinking i'm trying to convert the data. I just want to change the pixel format that the already existing gray data has been assigned.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should look into the [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format-1) filter.

Answer (score 0):

I think bayer support was added in ffmpeg for use with the MLV demuxer. It automatically debayers Magic Lantern files from bayer_rggb16le into your desired colorspace. That is the only way I know of to debayer video in ffmpeg. Support is currenly very basic. So if you could get your video in an MLV container you could debayer like this:

```
ffmpeg -i bayer-raw-input.mlv -pix_fmt yuv420p yuv-output.mp4
```